# Change of coordinates using Lebesgue area measure on $\mathbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, jacobian, change-of-variable

If I want to send $z \to \frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the following expression

$$ \int_{B(w, \beta)} e^{-|z|^2} dA(z)$$

where $B(w, \beta)$ is the Euclidean ball centered at $w$ with radius $\beta$ and $dA$ is the usual, normalized Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb C$, is there anyway to write the resulting expression as larger than some constant $C_{\beta}$ times

$$  \int_{B(w, \beta)} e^{\frac{-|z|^2}{2}} dA(z)?$$

I've never actually had to scale a variable in a transformation. Usually it's just a basic translation, which I can picture in my head more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $w = c z$ then
$$
\int_{B(a,r)} e^{-|z|^2} \, dA(z)
= \int_{B(ca,cr)} e^{-|w/c|^2} \, c^{-n} \, dA(w)
= c^{-n} \int_{B(ca,cr)} e^{-|w/c|^2} \, dA(w)
$$
where $n$ is the dimension of the space.

Comment: Yes, that much I figured. But is there a way to make the right hand integral greater than some constant depending only on c times the same integral but over $B(a,r)$ instead of $B(ca,cr)$?